# Sorting Time In Jumpstart Lab EventManager

Tags: ruby

Running into a problem here. Tried and tried, but am missing something...
Trying to get it to print the most popular hours from list of dates. Elsewhere, I found a solution here, which makes sense, but for me it doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
contents = CSV.open 'event_attendees.csv', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol

contents.each do |row|
  time = [row[:regdate]]
  time_target = Hash[time.group_by { |t| DateTime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour }.map{|k,v| [k, v.count]}]
  puts time_target
```

This puts the hour and a count on separate lines, but doesn't add up the count for hours that are repeated. Does that make sense? Here is a partial list of what I get when I try this:

```
{10=>1}
{13=>1}
{13=>1}
{19=>1}
{11=>1}
{15=>1}
{16=>1}
```

I am trying to get it to list in order of "most popular" hours. That is, the above should list 13=>2 first (since there are two 13 hours), rather than listing a count of one for each time. 
Why is what I am doing not adding together the count numbers for hours that are repeated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not putting the elements into the array. it should be something like this

```
times = contents.map { |row| row[:regdate] }
grouped = times.group_by { |t| DateTime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').hour }
time_target = Hash[grouped.map { |k, v| [k, v.count] }]
```

Comment: Thank you! Putting the elements in the array was exactly what I failed to do! This did the trick, and then I was able to sort them by the count values in ascending order.